# Apple APNS unregistered token repeatedly

Tags: apple-push-notifications

While running some tests, APNS pushes do not deliver any messages but the 
`application:applicationdidRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` method returns the same device token. And the feedback service keeps unregistering that device token.

```
token: EF71199500531549811F0881D92347BB4ABC73AA34A92839478C6500ED003909  date: 2018-10-02 13:48:08 +0000
token: EF71199500531549811F0881D92347BB4ABC73AA34A92839478C6500ED003909  date: 2018-10-02 14:09:35 +0000
token: EF71199500531549811F0881D92347BB4ABC73AA34A92839478C6500ED003909  date: 2018-10-02 15:19:23 +0000
token: EF71199500531549811F0881D92347BB4ABC73AA34A92839478C6500ED003909  date: 2018-10-02 15:29:25 +0000
```

Has anyone come across this behaviour before? And have any idea what is causing this?

Note: this does not seem to be a common problem, but it did happen on a clients device, so is a bit irritating.

If it is relevant the push and feedback where with NWPusher, and the app itself was an ad-hoc app, installed over-the-air to an iOS 12, iPhone X.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess as to what was causing this:

It seems that the feedback service will return the token multiple times if you keep sending pushes to a dead token.

And it is possible that the client did not accept notifications. In this situation iOS 12 (at least) does generate an initial device token. Not sure why, or if this has always been the case when no notifications are requested.

Then the design of the app meant that the original token, which was stored, was sent to our backend server on a login condition. making it look like it was being refresh.